# Change the bgcolor of array textbox if NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this input text which have a `name="quiztxtBox[]"`, as you can see, it is an `array`. I want to change the color of the bg of the textbox if the value of a certain textbox is `null`.

```
var quiztxtBox =  document.getElementById('quiztxtBox[]');
  for (i=0; i<quiztxtBox.length; i++)
      {
       if (quiztxtBox[i].value == "")
        {
          alert('Either question or answer is empty.');
          quiztxtBox[i].focus();
          quiztxtBox[i].css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"}); 
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** which is a jQuery function.

You should either include jQuery on your page, add cast your DOM element to a jQuery object and apply the the **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** function like so

Also you should be using getElementsByName

```
$(quiztxtBox[i]).css({..});
```

or just use vanilla JS as shown below

```
  var quiztxtBox =  document.getElementByName('quiztxtBox[]');
  for (i=0; i<quiztxtBox.length; i++) {
      if (quiztxtBox[i].value === "") {
          alert('Either question or answer is empty.');
          quiztxtBox[i].focus();
          quiztxtBox[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f6d9d4'; // this line 
      }
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/z3seW/)**

Comment: That should be .style.backgroundColor

Comment: That should do the trick, Also the return false should be remove, it terminate the loop in the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If your approach is correct, getElementById always returns one element and no collections, perhaps it would be better if you could get the collection of textboxes using

```
document.getElementsByName('quiztxtBox')
```

But remember you might have to update the name attribute of all your textboxes to something like

```
<input name="quiztxtBox" value="yourvalue" id="someuniquestuff1" />
<input name="quiztxtBox" value="yourvalue" id="someuniquestuff2" />
<input name="quiztxtBox" value="yourvalue" id="someuniquestuff3" />
<input name="quiztxtBox" value="yourvalue" id="someuniquestuff4" />
```

Thanks